# What's the final coalgebra of $F(S) = 1 + N \times S$ and initial algebra of $F(S) = N \times S$

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

There are 4 algebras in my mind and they make me very confusion.

I will list 2 (co)algebras which I can understand, and then list other 2 (co)algebras that I can not fully undertand.

- Given the functor $F(S) = 1 + \mathbb N \times S$,  the initial algebra of $F$ should be $(List \ \mathbb N, fix)$, where

```
fix : 1 + N x List N -> List N
fix * = []
fix (n, nx) = [n] ++ nx
```

- Given the functor $F(S) = \mathbb N \times S$, the final coalgebra of F should be $(Stream \ \mathbb N, unfix)$, where

```
 unfix : Stream N -> N x Stream N
 unfix s = (head(s), rest(s))
```

I can understand the these two (co)algebras above, but following two (co)algebras make me very confusion...

- Given the functor $F(S) = 1 + \mathbb N \times S$,  what is the final coalgebra of $F$?

  The carry object of this final coalgebra is $List \ \mathbb N$ or $Stream \ \mathbb N$?

  What is the struct map of this final coalgebra ?
- Given the functor $F(S) = \mathbb N \times S$,  what is the initial algebra of $F$?

  The carry object of this initial algebra is $\emptyset$ or $Stream \ \mathbb N$?

  What is the struct map of this initial coalgebra ?

The last question is what is the relationship among these 4 algebras and the induction /coinduction  types and greatest/least fixed points of $F$?

---

Edit for adding more information.

1. All $F$ appeared in the quesion are endofunctor $F : Set \to Set$.
2. All $\mathbb N$ appeared in the quesion are $Nat$ set.
3. $List \ \mathbb N$ means finite list of $\mathbb N$, $Stream \ \mathbb N$ means infinite stream of $\mathbb N$.
4. The functor $F(S) = 1 + \mathbb N \times S$, when it map morphism $f : S \to S'$

```
fmap : S -> S' -> 1 + N × S -> 1 + N × S'
fmap f * = *
fmap f (n, s) = (n, f s)
```

5. The functor $F(S)= \mathbb N ×S$, when it map morphism $f : S \to S'$

```
fmap : S -> S' -> N × S -> N × S'
fmap f (n, s) = (n, f s)
```

Comment: What do you mean by given 'a' functor $F(S) = 1 + \mathbb{N}\times S$, don't you want instead 'the' functor ? what's it's domain ? what does it do on morphisms ? You need to put more context, is your functor a monad on sets ? what is the monad structure that you are considering ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer Yes, I should use 'the' instead of 'a'. I added more information (e.g. How these functors map morphisms). No monad structure is involved.

Comment: that's better ! two lasts questions : is $[n] ++ nx$ the concatenation of the list $[n]$ and the list $nx$ ? and also what is Stream of $\mathbb{N}$  ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer Yes, the '++' concatenate two list. Here `[n] ++ nx` exactly means that `n : nx`, e.g. `n=9, nx=[1,2,3], n : nx = [9,1,2,3]`. Stream of N means infinite List of N, e.g. [1,2,3,4,...] is one element of Stream N.

Comment: Why would you think that there is a final coalgebra for the endofunctor $S\mapsto 1 + \mathbb{N}\times S$ ? Is there any reference where they hint to it beeing $Stream(\mathbb{N})$ ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer I don't have many references, but you can watch the video from https://youtu.be/0Q3NDZ6yxz0?list=PLhgq-BqyZ7i7MTGhUROZy3BOICnVixETS&t=2115 (at 35:15), David Spivak said that "This guy final coalgebra is possiblely infinite streams. The initial algebra is finite list, the final coalgebra is possiblely infinite streams."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer. I can't help you with the induction/coinduction types and greatest/least fixed points questions. I'm not sure what you mean by them.

The initial algebra of $F(S)=\newcommand\N{\Bbb{N}}\N\times S$ is definitely $\varnothing$. Since $F(\varnothing)=\varnothing$, we have a unique possible structure map $\varnothing \to \varnothing$, and since $\varnothing$ is initial in $\mathbf{Set}$, this is definitely the initial algebra.

The more interesting question is what is the final coalgebra (if it exists) for $F(S)= 1+\N\times S$.
By definition, this would be a set $S$ with map $\alpha : S\to F(S)$ such that for any other coalgebra $(T,\beta)$ there is a unique map $f:T\to S$ such that the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T@>\beta>> F(T) \\
@VfVV @VVF(f)V \\
S @>\alpha>> F(S) \\
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

Let's think about the meaning of a coalgebra for this functor for a moment.
It means that for each $t\in T$, we produce either $*$ or a pair $(n,t')$.
In other words, for each $t$ we can produce a stream of natural numbers that might be finite if at some point we reach $*$ or go on forever. 
Thus suggests that we should take 
$$S=\operatorname{List}(\N)\cup \operatorname{Stream}(\N)$$ in your notation. 
We should define $\alpha(\epsilon)=*$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty list and 
$\alpha(n_1n_2\cdots) = (n_1,n_2\cdots)$.

Then for any coalgebra $(T,\beta)$ we define $f$ recursively by 
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}
\epsilon & \beta(t)=* \\
nf(t') & \beta(t)=(n,t').
\end{cases}
$$

You can check that this makes the diagram commute and is the unique map doing so.

Comment: I note that in programming the second structure is sometimes called "colist".

Comment: @AndrásKovács Could you recommend some good references about "colist"/"codata" in programming? I will study it further. Especially, the connection among (co)algebras, induction/coinduction types and greatest/least fixed points of F.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete @jgon's answer, which did provide the initial algebra / final co-algebra that you were looking for.

Such initial algebras are (no matter the functor, as long as they exist) fixed points of $F$. To prove that, take $(A, s)$ an initial $F$-algebra, and consider $(F(A), F(s))$. By initiality, there is a unique map $s': A \to F(A)$ such that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(A) @> s >> A\\
@V F(s') VV @VV s' V\\
F(F(A)) @> F(s) >> F(A)
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.
But then,
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(A) @> F(s') >> F(F(A)) @> F(s) >> F(A)\\
@V s VV          @V F(s) VV         @V s VV\\
F @> s' >> F(S') @> s >> A
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, that is, $s\circ s'$ is an algebra map $(A, s) \to (A, s)$. So is the identity (F-algebra with their map form a category), so by unicity $s\circ s'=\mathrm{Id}$. The other direction is easy: $s' \circ s = F(s) \circ F(s') = F(s\circ s')=F(\mathrm{Id})=\mathrm{Id}$.

This means that $s$ is an isomorphism between $F(A)$ and $A$, which means $A$ is a fixed point (up-to-isomorphism) of $F$. The same goes for final co-algebras. Since initial algebras (resp. final co-algebras) are, in some way, the smallest algebras (resp. the biggest one), they are called least/greatest fixpoints of $F$.